# Is there a "memcpy" for R?

Tags: r

I work with large R objects that are sometimes accessed for read-only purposes by multiple people on our local network. For example, a reference class or [R6  object](https://github.com/wch/r6) might be used to store validation results related to a particular model, and it may have many read-only validation-related methods. I would like to keep using R to maintain workflow homogeneity and avoid moving to a language (like Java or Python) that would be more appropriate to solving the question I am about to ask.

Rather than instantiating these objects anew or reading them from serialized output (e.g., RDS or [redis](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppredis)) every time we need them in a new R session, it would be much more efficient to keep an active R process running on some server that is accessible on the network, and then "[memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)"ing objects from that server onto local machines: some kind of quasi-[object pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). Note these are sometimes legitimately non-tabular R objects that would be difficult to e.g. translate into a [database-backed object](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) (which might still be slower).

I understand that R maintains all information about what is in scope on the heap, so this may be difficult to do without control of the gc, but is it possible to "siphon" objects away from other R sessions on a byte-by-byte level using some sort of underlying C magic? I don't understand enough about how R manages objects in memory to know how to do this, but perhaps there is a package or snippets of existing code that can provide inspiration.

I am also willing to put on the straightjacket and make restrictions on the aforementioned objects that would make this task easier (e.g., can only reference certain packages, or the method definitions cannot be weird closures that would make this task impossible, or even can only be S3 objects).

EDIT: I just realized I haven't looked into [RProtoBuf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RProtoBuf/index.html). Could that be appropriate?

Comment: Maybe a modified version of the R console that can connect to an R "server" somewhere and is under-the-hood talking to that session, while maintaining different user spaces and a shared space that can be used to pass objects like this.

Comment: What you’re describing has precious little to do with classical `memcpy` – and a `memcpy` with network capabilities would also serialise the object and send it over the wire, similar to what you’d do with an RDS object. So why not use the latter? You say that it’s less efficient but I do not see any a priori reason for this.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to do this would be to serialize your objects into a stream of bytes that can be safely loaded on another machine at a later time.  This is exactly what the `base::serialize` method is for if everything is in R, or what [RProtoBuf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RProtoBuf) is for if the data needs to be shared between applications written in other languages.  In either case, you can write the serialized bytes to RDS or redis or any other data store.

Direct `memcpy` between machines would be problematic for many reason.  Most fundamentally, architectural differences between machines make this error prone if not all of your computers are the same endianness.  Also, you would have to find a way to represent complex data structures as a stream of bytes that could be interpreted on another machine.  Maybe things were loaded into memory at different addresses and so you can't just expect to do a raw memcpy without fixing up pointers to different memory locations, but if you are doing that, you are doing serialization, so again why not use `base::serialize` or `RProtoBuf`.

Comment: Good answer, +1'ed.  The RcppRedis package deals with all of this too, and as a side-effect spawned the RApiSerialize package getting us R's serialization at the C/C++ API level.